# How to calculate \sqrt{7+2\sqrt{10} } =

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> > $$
> > \sqrt[]{(\sqrt{7-2\sqrt[]{10}} + \sqrt[]{2})\cdot 2\sqrt[]{5}}
> > $$

I know that the answer is $\sqrt[]{10}$, but how do I calculate it mathematically if I don't have access to a calculator?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?  This can be algebraically manipulated but it's debatable whether or not any other form you'll get is any better than the current one.

Comment: Next time show efforts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

first note 
$\sqrt{7-2\sqrt{10}}=\sqrt{5+2-2\sqrt5\sqrt2}=\sqrt{(\sqrt5-\sqrt2)^2}=\sqrt5-\sqrt2$

hence

$$\sqrt[]{\big(\sqrt{7-2\sqrt[]{10}} + \sqrt[]{2}\big)\times2\sqrt[]{5}}=\sqrt5\sqrt2$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align} \sqrt{7-2\sqrt{10}} & =\sqrt{2+5-2\sqrt{10}} \\ &=\sqrt{(\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{2})^2} \\ \therefore \sqrt{\sqrt{5}\times 2\sqrt{5}} &=\sqrt{10} \end{align}$$

:)

Comment: The $\LaTeX$ command for a "centered" dot (multiplication) is `\cdot`.

Comment: That has been answered above

Comment: See the time difference i was typing while the answer was given

Comment: @hardmath we only use **\cdot** if we have a multi-variable equation. For example, we won’t write $2a\times b$ because $\times$ looks like another letter, namely $x$. Instead, we write $2ab$ or $2a\cdot b$ but the former is most common, unless $a$ and/or $b$ are represented as two seperate quotients. If we had something like $3\times 4$ then this would be ok, but the expression $3\cdot 4$ could come across as a decimal in certain countries which would arouse confusion